# Java Add Column with calculation to CSV file

Tags: java, csv, duration

How would I go about adding a new column to a CSV file, and adding caluculated data in each column?

example

`userid,expDate
1,012015
2,022016
3,032018`

I would take expDate from each row, calculate it relative to current month and year to get how many months till it expires, then round monthsTill (so monthsTill of next month will be 1, regardless if its the 1st day or last day of the current month)

`userid,expDate,monthsTill
1,022017,0
2,032017,1
3,042017,2
3,052017,3`

also how would you "skip" rows that have a certain value in there respective columns?

Comment: Are you open to using external libraries like apache commons csv and apache commons io ?

Comment: I would rather make the code as simple as possible, and if apache commons helps to do that and can be easily used i am open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your pseudo code, here is what should do the trick

```
private void process(){
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    PrintWriter p = null;
    String sep = ",";
    String newCol = "monthsTill";
    String defaultTillExpMonth = ">3";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(new Date());
    int currMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    try {
    // read csv file
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
   File inputFile = new File("InputFile");
  bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    String readLine = "";
    while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        input.add(readLine);
    }

 // for each row after first row
    // calculate timeTillExpired
        // if format MYYYY (ex 22017)
            // M and YYYY -> MM and YYYY

       // calculate relative to current date as months

    int numOfRecords = input.size();
    if(numOfRecords>1){
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        String header = input.get(0) +sep +newCol;
        output.add(header);

        // for each row after first row
        // calculate timeTillExpired
        // if format MYYYY (ex 22017)
              // M and YYYY -> MM and YYYY
        // calculate relative to current date as months
        for(int i=1;i<numOfRecords;i++){
            // I am simply going to get the last column from record
            String row = input.get(i);
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder(row);
            String [] entries = row.split(sep);
            int length = entries.length;
            if(length>0){
                res.append(sep);
                String rec = entries[length-1];
                int expMonth = 0;
                // Case of MYYYY. Assumption is it's either MYYYY or MMYYYY
                if(rec.length()==5){
                    expMonth = Integer.valueOf(rec.substring(0, 1));
                } else {
                    expMonth = Integer.valueOf(rec.substring(0, 2));
                }

                int monToExp = expMonth - currMonth;
                // if calculated > 3
                if(monToExp > 3){
                    res.append(defaultTillExpMonth);
                } else {
                    res.append(monToExp);
                }
                output.add(res.toString());
            }
        }
        // Write into the same file.
        // First We'll delete everything in the input file and then write the modified records

        p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt",false));
        // Ouch. Very bad way to handle resources. You should find a better way
        p.print("");
        p.close();
        // Write into file
        p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("InputFile"));
        for(String row : output)
        {
            p.println(row);
        }



    } else {
        System.out.println("No records to process");
    }



    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally { // Close file
        if(p!=null){
            p.close();
        }
        if(bufferedReader!=null){
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would strongly recommend you to understand what file resources are, how to handle them efficiently and improve this code. Later on you should move to Apache Commons Library

Comment: how is this making sure that it only gets the data from the 13th column of my data file? i just spent some time and wrote a seperate function that takes the input from that column and outputs a time till in months

example it would take in 22017, current date and year is 22017, so it would output 0, send int 22017 next month and it would output 1

Comment: It would be easier for me to have what calculates the time till to be a seperate function from what goes through the records.

Comment: I had put a comment under your pseudo code. Anyways, you can replace  if(length>0) , String rec = entries[length-1]; with if(length>12) and String rec = entries[12];

Comment: I agree. The logic of calculating time should be a separate and independent function.

Comment: Move the 3 statements LocalDate expDate = new LocalDate(yearResult, monthResult, day);
        LocalDate currDate = new LocalDate();
        int output = Months.monthsBetween(expDate, currDate).getMonths(); outside the if else block and call that method

Comment: only currDate = new LocalDate(); can be moved, the if and else are to account for different formats of date, it feeds it the raw data from the CSV, that way i can write the CSV reading and updating file without having to worry about how to handle the data, i just pass the data from that column of that row to the function and get a result back.

Comment: I have got a partialy working program now with a few issues
first, when i read STREET 2, in many cases it is blank, i want the new data file to follow the old style of replacing it with ,                                 , however every single time it does ,, as for my new data it puts it in, but it puts in the double quotes from the definition of the string, instead of the data itself, and it won't let me add a comma to the end (the original data had a comma at the end.

Comment: The original data had a comma at the end? It's conventional to pre-process your data into a correct format before you work on it. Also can you post an example of the problem you mentioned just now

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but the following piece of code should solve your problem.

```
List<String> input = FileUtils.readLines(new File("SomeFile"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(input.size()>1){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        String header = input.get(0) + ",monthsTill";
        output.add(header);
        int length = input.size();
        for(int i=1;i<length;i++){
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String row = input.get(i);
            String [] elements = row.split(",");
            if(elements.length == 2){
             // You have access to both the index and expiry date. So if you want to skip some row, simply don't add it to the ouput collection
                int exp = Integer.parseInt(elements[1].substring(0, 2));
                int monRemaining = month-exp;
                str.append(row).append(",").append(monRemaining);
                output.add(str.toString());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }

        FileUtils.writeLines(new File("SomeFile"), output, false);
```

Note that 'FileUtils' class is from APache Commons IO package

EDIT : If you don't want to use FileUtils, replace

```
List<String> input = FileUtils.readLines(new File("SomeFile"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

with

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
       File inputFile = new File("SomeFile");
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
       String readLine = "";
       while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
           input.add(readLine);
       }
```

and

```
 FileUtils.writeLines(new File("SomeFile"), output, false);
```

with

```
PrintWriter f0 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("SomeFile",false));
        f0.print("");
        // Erase the contents of the input file in a
        // Very bad way
        f0.close();
        f0 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
        for(String row : output)
        {
            f0.println(row);
        }
        f0.close();
```

Of course if you dont use Apache Commons IO, you will have to handle closing resources like streams etc yourself.

Comment: is there away to do this without apache commons? i can't find org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.

Comment: Apache Commons is not a part of Java SDK. You can use it as an external Jar or use a build tool like Maven - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4

Comment: I got all the files and get an error at throw new IllegalArgumentException();

Comment: if(elements.length == 2) checks if there are exactly 2 values separated by a comma. Is your input csv file proper?

Comment: that was a sample of the general idea, there are 13 columns in the actual data

Comment: the last column is the expiration date, the 11th column contains info on data i want to ignore. 

if the entry in column 11  = 1 i want to ignore that row of data

Comment: I am assuming by 11th column you mean 11th row and you want to get all the proper rows whilst ignoring the bad entries. In that case simply replace ' throw new IllegalArgumentException();' with something non-lethal like System.out.println("Something wrong with : +" i+" entry. Rectify");

Comment: I mean the 11th Column, I want to add an "monthsTill" column to the data, and then in each row of Data i want to insert data into the monthsTill column based on MED EXP DATE

this is the list of columns the first line of the CSV:

UNIQUE ID, FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, STREET 1, STREET 2, CITY, STATE, ZIP CODE, COUNTRY, REGION, MED CLASS, MED DATE, MED EXP DATE,

Comment: You should think each csv entry as an sql row. The statement String [] elements = row.split(","); will convert your csv entry into an array of individual elements. for instance if your entry is a,b,c then your elements would be {a,b,c} and you can access each with the respective index. Now if you want to convert a,b,c -> a,b,NEW,c I would suggest you put 2 for loops and put str.append(elements[i]).append(",") in each. The first loop will run from i=0 till 10. After that you append you new 'column' and the second for loop will run from i=11 till the last. So basically what you want to do is ...

Comment: ... get each row; get monTillExpiry and insert this value into your row at appropriate place

Comment: what is the simplest way to add blank data to the data so i can first add the column, then modify the data

Comment: There are many ways to do what you are asking. Something which could look simple to me might look complicated to you and vice versa. In the first row add the column name and for each subsequent row add a ',' in proper position. Both these steps could be done using the steps I listed above. One other way could be to use Serialize and DeSerialize option in Java. Perhaps what you just asked could be better done by a scripting language or even using notepad++. May I ask why you want to first add the column and then populate it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode of what i am trying to do

```
    // read csv file
        // append timeTillExpired to end of first row of CSV
        // for each row after first row
            // calculate timeTillExpired
                // if format MYYYY (ex 22017)
                    // M and YYYY
                    // calculate relative to current date as months
                //else
                    // MM and YYYY (ex 122017)
                    // calculate relative to current date as months
            // if calculated > 3
                // timeTillExpired = ">3"
                // add timeTillExpired to end of row
            //else
                // add timeTillExpired to end of row
    // save file
    // close file
```

Comment: How(on what basis?)/Where are you skipping rows?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function to calculate the time till

```
private static int calculateTimeTill(int date) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String numberAsString = Integer.toString(date);
    if(numberAsString.length() == 5)
    {
        //format 22017
        String month = numberAsString.substring(0,1);
        String year = numberAsString.substring(1,5);
        int monthResult = Integer.parseInt(month);
        int yearResult = Integer.parseInt(year);
        int day = 1;
        // using Joda - Time http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/installation.html
        // downloaded Joda - Convert as well
        LocalDate expDate = new LocalDate(yearResult, monthResult, day);
        LocalDate currDate = new LocalDate();
        int output = Months.monthsBetween(expDate, currDate).getMonths();
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        //format 122017
        String month = numberAsString.substring(0,2);
        String year = numberAsString.substring(2,6);
        int monthResult = Integer.parseInt(month);
        int yearResult = Integer.parseInt(year);
        int day = 1;
        // using Joda - Time http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/installation.html
        // downloaded Joda - Convert as well
        LocalDate expDate = new LocalDate(yearResult, monthResult, day);
        LocalDate currDate = new LocalDate();
        int output = Months.monthsBetween(expDate, currDate).getMonths();
        return output;
    }
}
```